# Bulkifying "SELECT COUNT()" in FOR-Loop

Tags: apex, trigger, bulk

My code updates a field in related records (Contacts) of a custom Object (ProductionOrganizer__c) on an "after update"-Trigger. In this process I add all removed lookups from `Trigger.oldMap` to `Map<Id, Contact> oldConts`. So my Map oldConts consists of all Contacts, that where in the lookups and have been removed in this execution-context.

Now I only want to update the Contact records with zero ProductionOrganizers in their related list. If a Contact is still related to with another ProductionOrganizer, he must not be touched. At the moment I'm achieving this with Count()-Aggregation in a for-loop, which is very bad practice as far as I know (but it works!)

So my question: Is there a possibility to populate my `List<Contact> contsWithoutOrgas` with one query? I'm pretty sure it could be feasible with some nested subqueries, but I'm not able to get this work.

```
if ( !oldConts.isEmpty() ) {
    oldConts.putAll([SELECT Id, IsOrganizer__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :oldConts.keySet()]);
    for ( Contact c : oldConts.values() ) {
        If ([SELECT Count() FROM ProductionOrganizer__c WHERE AttachedContactId__c = :c.Id] == 0 ) {
            c.IsOrganizer__c = false;
            contsWithoutOrgas.add(c);
        }
    }
    update contsWithoutOrgas;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like:

```
oldConts = [SELECT C.IsOrganizer FROM Contact C WHERE C.Id NOT IN(SELECT P.AttachedContactId__c FROM ProductionOrganizer__c P)];

for ( Contact c : oldConts) {
            c.IsOrganizer__c = false;
            contsWithoutOrgas.add(c);
        }
    }
    update contsWithoutOrgas;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Maps here to further simplify

```
if ( !oldConts.isEmpty() ) {
  map<Id,integer> mapCntIdByInteger = new map<Id,integer>();
  oldConts.putAll([SELECT Id, IsOrganizer__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :oldConts.keySet()]);
  for(AggregateResult ag:[SELECT Count(Id),AttachedContactId__c FROM ProductionOrganizer__c WHERE AttachedContactId__c IN  :oldConts.keySet() GROUP BY AttachedContactId__c ]){
    mapCntIdByInteger.put((Id)ag.get('AttachedContactId__c'),(integer)ag.get('expr0'));
  }
  for ( Contact c : oldConts.values() ) {
    if (mapCntIdByInteger.get(c.Id)== 0 ) {
        c.IsOrganizer__c = false;
        contsWithoutOrgas.add(c);
    }
  }
  update contsWithoutOrgas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the query to only query for leads/contacts that were changed in this specific trigger to minimize rows

```
oldLeads.putAll([SELECT L.IsOrganizer__c FROM Lead L WHERE L.Id NOT IN(SELECT P.AttachedLeadId__c 
                                                                       FROM ProductionOrganizer__c P) 
                 AND IsConverted = false
                 AND L.Id IN :beforLeadIdsCache]);

oldConts.putAll([SELECT C.IsOrganizer__c FROM Contact C WHERE C.Id NOT IN(SELECT P.AttachedContactId__c 
                                                                          FROM ProductionOrganizer__c P)
                                                        AND C.Id IN :beforContactIdsCache]);
```

Where `beforLeadIdsCache` is a Set of IDs I collect from `Trigger.old` that consists of the leads that are in `Trigger.old` but not in `Trigger.new`